# Spring (спринг) отправка сообщения конкретному пользователю через convertAndSendToUser

Tags: spring

отправка сообщения конкретному пользователю, используя SimpMessagingTemplate и SimpMessageHeaderAccessor кажется простой, но не работает в моем случае.
В чем может быть дело?

**Server:**

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@MessageMapping("/logon")
public void logon(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, UserInfo userInfo){
                this.template.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getSessionId(),"/queue/front/logon",  true, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
}
```

***Client:***

```
const socket = new SockJS(config.ws.address, undefined, { debug: true });
const client = new Client();
client.webSocketFactory = () => socket;
client.onConnect = () => {
client.subscribe('/user/queue/front/logon', message => {
    dispatch({
      type: WS.PKG_STATUS,
      data: +JSON.parse(message.body).id,
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых сессию в spring можно получить через **SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor** или **@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId**
Во-вторых организация очереди сессий лежит на плечах фронта:

**Server**

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@MessageMapping("/logon")
public void logon(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor){ 
//public void logon(@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId){                     
this.template.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getSessionId(),"/front/logon",  
true);
}
```

**Client**

```
const socket = new SockJS(config.ws.address, undefined, { debug: true });
const client = new Client();
client.webSocketFactory = () => socket;
client.onConnect = () => {
const sessionId = getSessionIdFromStomp(client);
const subscribePrefix = "/user/" + sessionId;
dispatch({ type: WS.CONNECT });
 client.subscribe(subscribePrefix + '/front/logon', message => {
    dispatch({
      type: MAIN.CALL_DATA,
      data: JSON.parse(message.body)
    })
  });
```